# Missing identifier in project model (json) which exists in manifest

Tags: java, gooddata

I have two projects: one is for development and another one is for integration tests. Project for integration tests is created from the template of the development project. This template I export by means of the following URL: https://goodata.com/gdc/projects/myProjectId/model/view

However, even though I'm using the template of the development, the integration tests project misses one field, which is date dimension attribute.

Am I missing something here? Should I export not only the project model listed above, but something else?

Thank you in advance for any help,
Dani

Answer (score 2):

The project model API support parameters which manage what is included in the response.

Please see API reference: https://help.gooddata.com/display/API/API+Reference#/reference/project-model/get-a-link-to-view-the-project-model/get-a-link-to-view-the-project-model

Try to include them and the missing attribute should appear.

Best,

Martin